# How to search from a UISearchBar using a URL

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I'm trying to search directly from the UISearchBar. I'm having problems with this and was wondering if there are any tutorials that cover this or if someone could help. here's my code:

```
-(void) searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

    if ([searchText length] == 0) {
        [displayItems removeAllObjects];

    } else {
        [displayItems removeAllObjects];

        NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://xml.customweather.com/xml?client=clinique_test&client_password=f@c3$toF&product=search&search=%@",searchBar.text];
        NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:5.0];

        }
    }

    // reload the table data
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Not too sure I understand what you are doing, if the user searches (like a city I guess) it will send a weather request and you use that data returned to present in your table view. What is going wrong here? Where is your NSURLConnection implementation? What do you want this code to do? It shouldnt really do anything at this moment

Comment: I know. I was wondering if there was some sample code I could follow that someone knows about. I really need something to reference to get this going. thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
 - (BOOL)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text 
    {
        NSString *trimDot = [text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

        if ([trimDot isEqualToString:@"."]) {
            return YES;
        }

    if(connection){
        [connection cancel];
    }
    NSString *appendStr;
       if([text length] == 0)
    {
        NSRange rangemak = NSMakeRange(0, [searchbar.text length]-1);
        appendStr = [searchbar.text substringWithRange:rangemak];
    }
    else
    {
        appendStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",searchbar.text,text];

    }
    [self performSelector:@selector(callSearchWebService:) withObject:appendStr];

    [activityindicator startAnimating];
    return YES;
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(callSearchWebService:) withObject:searchBar.text];
    searchBar.showsCancelButton=NO;

}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{   
    [self performSelector:@selector(callSearchWebService:) withObject:searchBar.text];
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

-(void)callSearchWebService:(NSString*)searchStr
{

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;

        NSString *str =@"";
        if ([searchStr length] != 0 ) str = searchStr;


        NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%d/%d/%@/",ListoutForSearcing_server,minRecords,maxRecords,str];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];

        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

        // Create Connection.
        connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

        if (connection) {
            JsonResponseData = [NSMutableData data] ;
            NSLog( @"Data will be received from URL: %@", request.URL );
        }
        else
        {// The download could not be made.
            NSLog( @"Data could not be received from: %@", request.URL );
        }
    HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.navigationController.view];
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:HUD];

    HUD.delegate = self;
    HUD.labelText = @"Loading";
    [HUD show:YES];
}
```

**Connection delegate methods**

```
#pragma mark Connection delegate methods.
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [JsonResponseData setLength:0];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [JsonResponseData appendData:data];   

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    UIAlertView *alertError=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Network Problem." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertError show];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    receivedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:JsonResponseData 
                                           encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    RecievedDataDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here from your code you use `URLConnection` with every character change in `UISearchBar` so it will not work perfect for you.

**NOTE**

Here you want to get data from web-server then here send request for that after you enter whole string in textfield of `UISearchBar` .. like in `searchBarSearchButtonClicked` method.

```
//RootViewController.m
- (void) searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar {

   [self searchTableView];
   [searchTableView reloadData];
}

- (void) searchTableView {

    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://xml.customweather.com/xml?client=clinique_test&client_password=f@c3$toF&product=search&search=%@",searchBar.text];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:5.0];
}
```

Comment: thanks :) that searches an nsarray though. I was looking for something that searches an online service and then presents the results in the tableView.

Comment: i put the Note bro.. see here for your requirement you send this request after user enetr whole string for search in textfield and when he click on search button then send this request just read tutorial just get some idea from that...

Comment: The link for the tutorial is dead.